# Uniqueness of the solution of an ODE with zero integral mean and convex $f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convex-analysis

> Consider the problem on $(0,1)$
>   $$u(x)'=f(u(x))$$
>   $$\int_0^1u(x)dx=0$$
>   where $f$ is $C^1$ on the whole real line, strictly convex, has its minimum in $0$, and $f(0)<0$.
>   Prove that the solution is unique.

I tried two ways: to reduce the problem to a Cauchy problem, showing that the condition on the mean, together with the properties of $f$, implies some 'initial-value' condition; or to apply the contraction principle (i.e. showing that the Fredholm operator associated to $f$ is a contraction). But I have not been able to follow any of these ways.

Can someone give a help, also explaining, if possible, useful strategies to apply in similar cases (i.e. 'modified' Cauchy problems)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi_x(u_0)$ be the solution of the ode for $u(0)=u_0$.
Then $\phi_x(v_0)> \phi_x(u_0)$ for $v_0>u_0$ (by uniqueness of solutions to ode) for $x$ values for which both exist. So their integrals are also distinct. This shows uniqueness.

To get existence note that if $f(u_0)<0$ then $\phi_x(u_0)$ exists and is  a decreasing function for all  $x\geq 0$. For $u_0=0$ the integral is therefore negative. If $f\geq -M$ then $\phi_x(u_0)\geq u_0-Mx$ so for $u_0$ large enough the integral becomes positive. By the IVT there is a unique $u_0$ for which the integral vanishes. Convexity is not of importance. Neither is the fact that the minimum of $f(u)$ is for $u=0$.

Comment: Thank you! The fact that $0$ is not in the domain can be bypassed by saying that the same equation has however a solution on $[0,1]$ as you showed?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but the essential properties is that $f$ has a lower bound (or else solutions need not exist on the whole interval $[0,1]$) and that $f(0)<0$ so that the 'relevant' (those with $f(u_0)<0$) solutions decrease and because of the previous exist (for all times in fact).

Comment: I was just clearing that $u(0)$ could not exist, a priori (the problem is in $(0,1)$), but this shouldn't be a problem, right? By the way, it is strange that these additive informations are useless. EDIT: why must $f$ remain negative when $u(x)$ decreases, for $x$ getting far from $0$? Thank you again.

Comment: Ok, I see. But no, it's not a problem. One may indeed specify the value of $u(0)$. The last is because for $f$ to become positive you have to cross a point where it is zero. But if $f(a)=0$ and $u(x_0)=a$  then $u(x)=a$ is the unique solution and you can not cross this by another solution (a barrier) due to Cauchy-Lipschitz.